# R: Create summary table using T1 data for all groups, and T2 data for one group only

Tags: r, summary, summarize, gtsummary

I am trying to create a summary table in R of baseline (T1) scores for all participants, grouped by another column with three variables (Group1, Group2, Group3), as well as outcome scores for Group3 only, as Group1 and Group2 do not have this data. I would like the table to look something like this (I have T1 and T2 there as headers above headers but I can't figure out how to do this here):

```
                                                     T1                                        T2
```

|  | Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| measure1 | Score | Score | Score | Score |
| measure2 | Score | Score | Score | Score |
| measure3 | Score | Score | Score | Score |
| measure4 | Score | Score | Score | Score |

My data are currently in wide format but I've also transformed it into long format to see if it would be achieveable this way but no success yet with any method I've chosen.

My variables in wide format would be = group, measure1_t1, measure2_t1, measure_3t1, measure4_t1, measure1_t2, measure2_t2, measure3_t2, measure4_t2.

In long format, these would be group, time, measure1, measure2, measure3, measure4

Would anyone have any advice on how I could achieve this? I can't seem to get it without including columns for group2 and group3 for the measures for T2. So far, I've tried using gt_summary and dplyr::summarise but with no success, but I'm open to using other packages/functions.

Alternatively, if there's a way to combine two tables to achieve this instead of doing one table only I'm happy to explore that option

Thanks

Comment: please share your data with `dput(df)` and the code your have tried to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this through creating two separate tables using table_summary and using table_merge to bring them together.

First table:

```
# Filtering dataset to include only T1 data, and selecting relevant variables.
t1_prep <- df %>%
  dplyr::filter(time == "t1") %>%
  dplyr::select(group, measure1, measure2, measure3, measure4)

#Creating the summary table
t1_sum <- t1_prep %>%
  tbl_summary(by = group,
              statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"),
              missing_text = "Missing"
              ) %>%
  add_overall() %>%
  add_n() %>%
  modify_header(label ~ "**Variable**") %>%
  modify_footnote(
    all_stat_cols() ~ "Mean (SD)"
  )
```

Second table

```
# Filtering dataset, this time to specify at T2, and group 1 only. In select, no longer choose the group variable as this is no longer wanted. 
t2_prep <- df %>%
  dplyr::filter(time == "t2", group == "Group1") %>%
  dplyr::select(measure1, measure2, measure3, measure4)

t2_sum <- t2_prep %>%
  tbl_summary(by = NULL,
              statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"),
              missing_text = "Missing") %>%
 add_n() %>%
#Note that must specify the group and number included in that group below for consistency when merging the tables - this would only state N = 65 otherwise
  modify_header(label ~ "**Variable**", all_stat_cols()  ~ "**Completer** N = 65") %>%
  modify_footnote(
    all_stat_cols() ~ "Mean (SD)"
  )
```

Merging

```
t1_t2_merge <-
  tbl_merge(
    list(t1_sum, t2_sum),
    tab_spanner = c("**Pre-Intervention**", "**Post-Intervention**")
  )  %>%
   as_gt() %>% #this and belowis not necessary but I wanted to add styling
  gt::tab_options(table.font.names = "Times New Roman") %>%
  gt::opt_row_striping() 
t1_t2_merge
```

Answer (score 1):

The {gtsummary} package exports a function `tbl_strata()` just for this purpose. https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_strata.html

```r
tbl_strata_ex1 <-
  trial %>%
  select(age, grade, stage, trt) %>%
  mutate(grade = paste("Grade", grade)) %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = grade,
    .tbl_fun =
      ~ .x %>%
        tbl_summary(by = trt, missing = "no") %>%
        add_n(),
    .header = "**{strata}**, N = {n}"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried this however and it's still trying to provide me with T2 data for groups 2 and 3. What I'm looking for is like having Grade I as is above, but for Grade II and Grade 3, only having Drug A (because it is all NAs for Drug B for Grade II and Grade III)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're saying. Please include sample data as Mike indicated in the comments. If you're by variable is a factor, it will include columns when there is no data present. If, however, you're by variable is character, they will not be shown.